# Can not download dynamically generated local xlsx file in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an angular 5 application with a folder containing dynamically generated xlsx file in it as belowe

[image]

when I try to download that excel file using below code

```
<a href='assets/excel.xlsx'>Download</a>
```

It is redrirecting me to ,

http://localhost:4200/assets/excel.xlxs/

but the file is not downloading.

anybody please tell me how to do this ?

Comment: you like to view this or download this

Comment: I just want to download it

Comment: ok can you share your code or put it on stackbiz

Comment: I did nt write any angular code to download this file yet. Can you please suggest me one

Comment: hello please check the  answer then apply it will work and reply me please about the status

Answer (score 0):

***Please try like this  it will work if just want to download file on click***

[image]

```
<a href='assets/changes_status.xlsx'>Download</a>
```

Like this

```
<a href='ExcelExport/excel.xlxs'>Download</a>
```

Comment: I have tried this. but when i click on the download link it just redirect me to home page with url as http://localhost:4200/assets/excel.xlxs. File is not downloading.

Comment: <a href='assets/excel.xlxs'>Download</a>

Comment: put your code please all becuse test before i gave you and it working on my system

Comment: I have added that excel file within assets folder and used below code to download <a href='assets/excel.xlxs'>Download</a>

Comment: the file is a dynamically generated file